# Is there a way to draw-lock the bow and release with a second click?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Every once in a while, I will notice that I'll draw the bow and it will remain drawn when I release the button.  The majority of the time, though, the arrow fires when I release the button.  However, I like it when it locks like that because it takes the fatigue out of holding down the button while aiming, especially when it's a dragon fight.

Is this just some beneficial bug or am I inadvertently triggering some in-game feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it happen more often when you are moving? [This](http://www.gameskyrim.com/arrow-premature-release-t210957.html) thread seems to indicate that this is a bug.